# Adding dynamicly require() file in expo-av

Tags: react-native, expo-av

I want to add something like that require(`./assets/`+variable). But require() doesn't support that.

```
const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(
  
  require(`./assets/`+variable)
  
);
```

Answer (score -1):

require takes a string which is a path to the asset.  you can do something like this:

const path = "./assets/" + variable;
require(path);

or:

require(`./assets/${variable}`);

Comment: No It does not Working